# Sticking card header at the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `bootStrap` card in my template, whose skeleton is like this -

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
```

I want to keep **card-header** fixed at the top while scrolling down the **card-block**. How can I do that ?

As far as I know, `Bootstrap` has a class for fixing nav-bar at the top. But I couldn't find anything for **card-header**.

**EDIT:** i need a solution which will not effect any cards (if i add any) within **card-block**.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking something like this ? [LiveOnFidde](https://jsfiddle.net/8y3xfssp/) If you have any question ask me in comment.

```css
.card-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #bbb;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 20px;
}

.card-block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
Featured

  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
<h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional contentWith supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural</p>
<p class="card-text">  lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.With
  supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content..
</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fixed vs sticky
https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by CSS, using a JavaScript Polyfill:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042

Comment: do you have this example working in a sandbox? Use case is: it is somewhere on screen and when you scroll and card header reaches the top of the page then it is expected to become sticky and stay visible on top. If user scroll down card header is expected to follow the card content.